# Prove that $\left[\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt[d_1]{a_1},...,\sqrt[d_n]{a_n}\right]:\Bbb Q\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$.

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, kummer-theory

I am trying to prove the following quoted statement.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $r_1,...,r_n$ be *real* algebraic integers over $\Bbb Q$ with minimal polynomials  $x^{d_1}-a_1,...,x^{d_n}-a_n$, respectively. Then the equality $$\left[\Bbb Q[r_1,...,r_n]:\Bbb Q\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$$holds if and only if for all $s_i\in\Bbb Z$, $$\prod_{i=1}^nr_i^{s_i}\in \Bbb Q$$implies $s_i\equiv 0$ modulo $d_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

I will sketch a proof that is "almost done", requiring some technical modifications.

Let $m=\operatorname{lcm}(d_1,...,d_n)$, let $\omega$ be a primitive $m^{th}$ root of unity and let $\mu_m(\Bbb Q)$ to be the group of all $m^{th}$ root of unity over $\Bbb Q$. For clarity set $\Bbb Q_{\omega}:=\Bbb Q[\omega]$ and $E=\Bbb Q_{\omega}[r_1,...,r_n]$. Define the *large Kummer group* $$\operatorname{KUM}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)=\{r\in E:r^m\in\Bbb Q_{\omega}^{\times}\}$$and define the *small Kummer group* to be the quotient $$\operatorname{kum}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)=\operatorname{KUM}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)/\Bbb Q_{\omega}^\times.$$Since $\Bbb Q_{\omega}^{\times}$ contains all $m^{th}$ roots of unity, the group $\operatorname{Gal}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)$ is abelian and the map $$\operatorname{Gal}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)\times \operatorname{kum}(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega})\to\mu_m(\Bbb Q)$$defined by $$(\sigma,r)\mapsto\frac{\sigma(r)}{r}$$is bilinear as $\Bbb Z$-modules. Moreover it is non-degenerate by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory and the fact that a Galois automorphism is determined by the values of the generators. Since both $\operatorname{Gal}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)$ and $\operatorname{kum}(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega})$ are finite abelian and $\mu_m(\Bbb Q)$ is finite cyclic,  It is a group theory exercise that then $$\operatorname{Gal}\left(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}\right)\simeq \operatorname{kum}(E/\Bbb Q_{\omega}).$$

The case where $m=d_1=...=d_n=2$in Theorem 1 is proved, since $\Bbb Q_{\omega}=\Bbb Q$  and the list of elements of them form $\prod_{i=1}^nr_i^{s_i}$ for $0\leq s_i\leq d_i-1$ gives $\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$ distinct cosets in $\operatorname{kum}(E/\Bbb Q)$ while spanning the extension $E/\Bbb Q$. So one must have $$\prod_{i=1}^nd_i\leq \operatorname{kum}(E/\Bbb Q)=\operatorname{Gal}(E/\Bbb Q)\leq \prod_{i=1}^nd_i$$as needed.

However, the general case of Theorem 1 does not follow directly from the isomorphism between the small kummer group and the Galois group. Consider the case where $r_1=\sqrt{3},r_2=\sqrt[4]{5},r_3=\sqrt[3]{7}$. Then the extension $$\Bbb Q_{\omega}\left[\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[3]{7}\right]=\Bbb Q\left[i,\sqrt 3\right]\left[\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[3]{7}\right]=\Bbb Q\left[i,\sqrt 3,\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[3]{7}\right].$$The products of the $r_i$'s in the small kummer group are *NOT* distinct as $\sqrt 3\in\Bbb Q_{\omega}$, so gives the same cosets if multiplied by another $r_i$. But I believe Theorem 1. in this case is indeed correct, while one needs some technical modifications.

Is there an elegant way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to prove the following theorem, which implies the theorem in the question by looking at linear independence.

> **Theorem 1.1.** Let $p_1,...,p_m$ be distinct positive primes and $n\in\Bbb Z_+$. Then$$\left[\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt[n]{p_1},...,\sqrt[n]{p_m}\right]:\Bbb Q\right]=n^m.$$

Let $E_n=\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt[n]{p_1},...,\sqrt[n]{p_m}\right]$. As mentioned in the question the equality $$\left[E_2:\Bbb Q\right]=\left[\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_m}\right]:\Bbb Q\right]=2^m$$has been established. Although the cyclotomic extension of $\Bbb Q$ might contain square roots (in fact every square root of a positive integer is contained in some cyclotomic extension of $\Bbb Q$,) we could build upon the obtained equality $[E_2:\Bbb Q]=2^m$ and show that higher roots does not appear to be contained in a cyclotomic extension of $\Bbb Q$.

The first lemma is some well-known facts that we are going to use.

> **Lemma 1.** The following results about irreducibility of polynomials hold.
>
> $(i)$. If $p\in\Bbb Z_+$ is a prime, $a\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$ and $\sqrt[p]{a}\notin\Bbb Q$, then $x^p-a$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.
>
> $(ii).$ If $a\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$ and $\sqrt[4]{a}\notin\Bbb Q$, then $x^4-a$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

In the sense of Kronecker–Weber theorem, the following lemma says that higher roots of positive integers are not contained in a cyclotomic field.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $n,k\in\Bbb Z_+$. Then $\operatorname{Gal}\left(\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[n]{k}\right]/\Bbb Q\right)$ is abelian iff $\left(\sqrt[n]{k}\right)^2\in\Bbb Q$.

*Proof.* The case of either $n$ or $k$ being $1$ is obvious. Assume now $n,k>1$.

If $\left(\sqrt[n]{k}\right)^2\in\Bbb Q$, write $\sqrt[n]{k}=\sqrt{a}$ for some $a\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$. Then $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt{a}\right]$ must be abelian as the composition of abelian Galois extensions $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q[\omega_n]$ and $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt{a}\right]$.

Conversely assume $\left(\sqrt[n]{k}\right)^2\notin\Bbb Q$, and write $\sqrt[n]{k}=\sqrt[r]{t}$ with the smallest positive integer $r$ possible. Clearly then $r|n$ and $r>2$. Note that $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right]=\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[n]{k}\right]$ is Galois as $\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right]$ is the splitting field of $x^n-k$ over $\Bbb Q$.

***Case 1.*** If $r$ contains an odd prime factor $p$, then $\sqrt[p]{t}\notin\Bbb Q$ as well and$$\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_p,\sqrt[p]{t}\right]\subset\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right],$$where all extensions above are Galois. To prove $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian it suffices to prove $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_p,\sqrt[p]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian. By the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials and **Lemma 1.$(i)$**, there are $\sigma,\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}\left(\Bbb Q\left[\omega_p,\sqrt[p]{t}\right]/\Bbb Q\right)$ such that $$\sigma(\omega_p)=\omega_p,\tau(\omega_p)=\omega_p^2~\text{ and }~\sigma\left(\sqrt[p]{t}\right)=\omega_p\sqrt[p]{t},\tau\left(\sqrt[p]{t}\right)=\sqrt[p]{t}.$$But $\sigma$ and $\tau$ does not commute on $\sqrt[p]{t}$ as $$\sigma\tau\left(\sqrt[p]{t}\right)=\omega_p\sqrt[p]{t}~\text{ and }~\tau\sigma\left(\sqrt[p]{t}\right)=\omega_p^2\sqrt[p]{t},$$showing that $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_p,\sqrt[p]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian.

***Case 2.*** If $r$ is a power of $2$, then $4|r$, $\sqrt[4]{t}\notin\Bbb Q$ and $$\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_4,\sqrt[4]{t}\right]\subset\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right]$$where all extensions above are Galois. To prove $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[\omega_n,\sqrt[r]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian it suffices to prove $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_4,\sqrt[4]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian. By the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials and **Lemma 1.$(ii)$**, there are $\sigma,\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}\left(\Bbb Q\left[\omega_4,\sqrt[4]{t}\right]/\Bbb Q\right)$ such that $$\sigma(\omega_4)=\omega_4,\tau(\omega_4)=\omega_p^3~\text{ and }~\sigma\left(\sqrt[4]{t}\right)=\omega_4\sqrt[4]{t},\tau\left(\sqrt[4]{t}\right)=\sqrt[4]{t}.$$But $\sigma$ and $\tau$ does not commute on $\sqrt[4]{t}$ as $$\sigma\tau\left(\sqrt[4]{t}\right)=\omega_4\sqrt[4]{t}~\text{ and }~\tau\sigma\left(\sqrt[4]{t}\right)=\omega_4^3\sqrt[4]{t},$$showing that $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q\left[\omega_4,\sqrt[4]{t}\right]$ is non-abelian.$\square$

Now clearly $$n^m\geq [E_n:\Bbb Q]\geq[E_{2n}:E_2]\geq [E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]:E_{2}[\omega_{2n}]]$$by the diagram below.
[image: Lattice of Extensions]

By Kummer Theory it suffices to show the estimate $$\#\operatorname{kum}\left(E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]/E_2[\omega_{2n}]\right)\geq n^m.$$

> **Lemma 3.** For all $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ the estimate $\#\operatorname{kum}\left(E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]/E_2[\omega_{2n}]\right)\geq n^m$ holds.

*Proof.* Define the obvious generating set $$B_{2n}^2=\Bigl\{\sqrt[2n]{p_1^{s_1}...p_m^{s_m}}:0\leq s_i\leq n-1\Bigr\}$$for $E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]$ over $E_2[\omega_{2n}]$. I claim $B_{2n}^2$ gives distinct cosets in $\operatorname{kum}\left(E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]/E_2[\omega_{2n}]\right)\geq n^m$.

Let us fix $r\in B_{2n}^2$. It remains show $r\in \left(E_2[\omega_{2n}]\right)^\times$ implies $r=1$.

The extensions $\Bbb Q\subset E_2$ and $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q[\omega_{2n}]$ are Galois and abelian, so should their composition $\Bbb Q\subset E_2\Bbb Q[\omega_{2n}]$. If $r\in \left(E_2[\omega_{2n}]\right)^\times$ then $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[r,\omega_{2n}\right]\subset E_2\Bbb Q[\omega_{2n}]$ so that the Galois group of $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[r,\omega_{2n}\right]$ is a quotient of that of $\Bbb Q\subset E_2\Bbb Q[\omega_{2n}]$, which must be abelian.

Assume $r\neq 1$. Clearly $r^2\notin\Bbb Q$. **Lemma 1** shows $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q\left[r,\omega_{2n}\right]$ is nonabelian, contradiction.$\square$

We have proved a stronger result that $$[E_n:\Bbb Q]=[E_{2n}:E_2]= [E_{2n}[\omega_{2n}]:E_{2}[\omega_{2n}]]=n^m.$$